# Server response shows in page and can't handle it in client side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, fetch

I'm using fetch to send data to express app, but the response just appear in the page and i can't handle it.
server-side:

```
res.status(200).json({"email":`signup/confirm-email?v=${req.body.email}`});
```

client-side

```
$(".form-div form input[type='submit']").click(async function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        await form = {
            username: document.getElementsByName('username').value,
            email:  document.getElementsByName('email').value,
            password: document.getElementsByName('password').value
        }
        fetch("/signup", {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({form})
        })
        .then(res=>{
            if (!res.ok) {
                throw Error(res.statusText);
            };
            return res;
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res=>{
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            console.log("ac", err);
        });
    });
```

Before, when i was using jquery to  send the data, I was able to handle it.
I believe that the problem is not from server-side because i deleted all the code except the line above.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: this code is bananas. the fuck? using `await` to declare the `form` variable. `async` to declare the callback function? and using jquery to boot? the hell is going on here clark?

Comment: I thought it was correct the server gets the form fields